# JavaScript expanding div doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I have a script that lets you put a link at the bottom of some text so you can reveal more text.  It works great in Firefox.  When you click the link, the div appears and the other parent divs expand with the growing child div. But the parent divs don't expand in IE.  The text actually disappears behind the row (this is in a table created with divs) below.  I want it to push the next row down so that the rest of the text appears.

Also, my images seem larger in IE than they are in Firefox. Can I scale the images a little bit with a conditional statement?  If so, how?

Comment: can't do anything without the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using something like the [JQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)? It's a quick way to accomplish something like you're going for, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you have more than one problem, anyway images with fixed sizes should render the same across browsers. For the first problem with the link you should post some code. I suggest you to check if your script throws some errors in IE using the IE developer toolbar (bundled with IE8 or [downlodable here from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en))